# Crashlytics not sending crash report instead showing red screen with error message

Tags: android, react-native, crashlytics

Iam integrating crashlytics in my react native application.To test crash i am accessing a undeclared variable.But the app is not crashing instead it is "showing null is not an object" in red screen.I know that crash will be sent when the app shows unfortunately closed. I am building the app instead of directly running and installing it in device and testing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can force a crash by calling:

```
throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
```

You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/test-crash.html#cause-a-test-crash).

Comment: Thank you but I am implementing it in react native.Getting error but instead of crashing the app is showing error screen.